# What is the name of the less-than symbol mysql uses to ingest sql files?

Tags: mysql, bash, io-redirection

When I want mysql to run a sql file, I use a command like this:

`mysql -uroot -prootpass dbname < dump.sql`

What is the name of the operator that is the less-than sign in this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [redirection operator](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

You can read up in your shell's manfile as well: `man bash` (for instance) reads

> Before  a  command  is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell.
>   [...]
>   Redirection of input causes the file whose name results from the
>   expansion of word to be opened for reading on file descriptor n, or
>   the standard input (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified.